# Error in HTTP POST request from Flask docker container to Tensorflow/Serving container

Tags: docker, http, flask, docker-compose, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to deploy my micro projects using docker compose on AWS EC2. The images of major containers are Nginx, Flask, MySQL, and Tensorflow/Serving.

I have successfully made connection between Flask container and DB in MySQL container for sending select query to the DB and receive correct result back to Flask,

**but yet I am failing to make connection between Flask and Tensorflow/Serving for sending input as a HTTP POST request to a saved Keras model (folder including .pb file) and receive the prediction back to Flask.**

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginxproxy:
    depends_on:
      - nginx
      - db
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: proxyserver 
    restart: always 
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./myweb:/usr/share/nginx/html

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: mywebserver 
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./myweb:/usr/share/nginx/html

  flask:
    build: ./flask_docker
    restart: always
    container_name: myflask
    command: gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:80 wsgi:server
    links:
      - tf

  tf:
    image: tensorflow/serving
    restart: always
    container_name: mytf
    volumes:
      - ./exportedmodel:/models/test_model
    environment:
      - MODEL_NAME=test_model
    expose:
      - "8501"

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysqldb 
    volumes:
      - mydb:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw

volumes:
  mydb:
```

For the connection between Flask and DB in MySQL, the python code below in Flask has worked well. I got the correct result for my select query.

```py
db = pymysql.connect(
        host='mysqldb', # container name
        port=3306, 
        user='root',
        passwd='rootpw',
        db='mydatabase', 
        charset='utf8')
cursor = db.cursor()
```

However, for the connection between Flask and Tensorflow/Serving, the code below in Flask shows error.

```py
data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": [input_id]}) # [input_id] is the input for the DL model

headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
json_response = requests.post('http://mytf:8501/v1/models/test_model:predict', data=data, headers=headers) # /models/test_model includes .pb file, the Keras model
result = json_response.json()
```

The error message is:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='mytf', port=8501): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/models/test_model:predict (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4aecd595e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Why does the POST request fail, though I have set the port expose and links in the docker-compose.yml?

(p.s. - I did not install the full Tensorflow in the Flask container, because while I tried the Flask container was killed, probably due to memory exceed. So installation of the full Tensorflow is not in my option.)

I have tried to change 'mytf' in request.post into localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, container ID, but all of the attempts have failed. The HTTPConnectionPool problem still exists.

Comment: (`expose:` and `links:` are obsolete artifacts of first-generation Docker networking, and you can safely remove them from your Compose file.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

Previously, the files including 'saved_model.pb' were in the folder 'exportedmodel'.

I created a folder named '0001' under the folder 'exportedmodel', and I moved the files into 'exportedmodel/0001'.

(Note: I did not change the contents of docker-compose.yml.)

Then surprisingly, it works!

(Maybe... because the path for HTTP POST request includes 'v1'??)

I referred to chapter 19 of "Hands-On Machine Learning" (2nd Ed.) written by Aurélien Géron.